# jQuery click events working only for once, but second time its not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jQuery click events working only for once, but second time its not [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/djsSq/189/)

```
$('.animateBtn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('OFF');
    $(this).next('div').addClass('animate');
    var btnText = $(this).text('Aniamte ON');    
    if($(this).next('div').hasClass('animate')) {
        $(this).text('Aniamte OFF')        
    }   
    $('.OFF').on('click', function() {    
        if($(this).hasClass('OFF')){
            $(this).removeClass('OFF');
            $(this).next('div').removeClass('animate');
            $(this).text('Aniamte ON')  
        }
    })    
})
```

Comment: jsfiddle link not working

Comment: I wouldn't nest the on click function of the OFF class.

Comment: It's a little overcomplicated here...every time you call the '.animateBtn' callback you are adding a listener to '.OFF'

Comment: updated the link of fiddle

Comment: @Barmar, here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/djsSq/189/, here the scenario is different.

Comment: When you click the second time it first runs the `.animateBtn` handler, which adds the `OFF` class. Then it runs the `.OFF` handler, which checks whether it has the `OFF` class, removes it, and stops the animation.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree with your comment, but the is issue when
1. At first when i click animate ON button i'm adding the animate class to div and even changing the text ON to OFF. 2. Again after clicking on OFF removing the animate class from div. But the Issue is again if i click on ON i can't able to add animate class to the respective div.

Comment: It's also generally a bad idea to bind handlers inside other handlers. Every time you click on `.animateBtn` it adds a duplicate handler to `.OFF`. So then the `.OFF` handler runs multiple times when you click on it.

Comment: If you single-step through the code with the Javascript debugger, you'll see that it adds the animate, and then immediately removes it. Because both handlers are running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78762/discussion-between-stanze-and-barmar).

Comment: can you please update the required code in my fiddle to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation to deal with dynamically changing classes.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.animateBtn', function () {
    $(this).addClass('OFF').removeClass('animateBtn');
    $(this).next('div').addClass('animate');
    var btnText = $(this).text('Aniamte ON');
    $(this).text('Aniamte OFF');
});
$(document).on('click', '.OFF', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('OFF').addClass('animateBtn');
    $(this).next('div').removeClass('animate');
    $(this).text('Aniamte ON')
});
```

```css
.animate {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: slide 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: slide 2s linear;
    animation: slide 2s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 100px 0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 100px 0;
    }
}
@keyframes slide {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 100px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class="animateBtn">Animate ON</button>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use event delegation for dynamic element

```
 $(document).on('click','.OFF', function() {
```